# Realm not working after stoping running app?

Tags: realm

I am testing Realm by adding 2000 records to it. Problem is that when i stopped running application the deleteAllObject method is not calling even any line is not executing. I think problem in beginWriteTransaction method.

This is my code:

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

    [realm deleteAllObjects];

    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2000; i++) {

        [realm beginWriteTransaction];

        PeopleInformation *info = [[PeopleInformation alloc] init];

        info.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d",@"Rohit",i];
        info.city = @"Delhi";

        [realm addObject:info];
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];

    }

NSLog(@"all object %@", [PeopleInformation allObjects]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Problem is that when i stopped running application...'? Are you explicitly trying to quit the app mid-execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is halting at the first `[realm beginWriteTransaction];` statement, that would seem to imply that another write transaction is already open somewhere else.

Realm only allows one transaction to modify the data on disk at a time, and it intentionally stops any new transactions starting until the current one has finished. I'd recommend looking into that for starters. You can check to see if a `RLMRealm` is already in a transaction through the `-[RLMRealm inWriteTransaction]` property. :)

Additionally, Realm works better if you batch writes into as few transactions as possible. Since you're opening and closing a transaction for each iteration in that `for` loop, you're creating 2000 separate transactions there, which could easily slow Realm down.

Your code might run more quickly if you structured it like this instead:

```
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 2000; i++) {
    PeopleInformation *info = [[PeopleInformation alloc] init];

    info.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d",@"Rohit",i];
    info.city = @"Delhi";

    [realm addObject:info];
}
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Let me know if that helped at all!

Comment: thanks it's really help full. So here we are adding a batch ?

Comment: My pleasure! Yeah, you're batching all of the object insertions into only one write transaction.